# Error "local variable 'born' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python

```
def singers_band_info(url, pagetext):
    get_soup = lambda page:BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    get_rows = lambda soup:soup.find_all("tr")
    get_cols = lambda row:row.find_all("th") + row.find_all("td")
    get_colstd = lambda row:row.find_all("td")
    rows = get_rows(get_soup(pagetext))
    for row in rows:
        cols = get_cols(row)
        colstd = get_colstd(row)
        if cols[0].get_text() == "Born":
            try:
                born = colstd[0].get_text()
                born = born[1:11]
            except:
                born = "False"
        if cols[0].get_text() == "Years active":
            try:
                ya = colstd[0].get_text()
            except:
                ya = "False"
        if cols[0].get_text() == "Genres":
            try:
                genres = colstd[0].get_text()
            except:
                genres = "False"
    singer_band_info_d = dict(url = url, genres = genres, born = born, ya = ya)
    return singer_band_info_d
```

Comment: When the code gets to execute the line before the last one: `singer_band_info_d = dict(url = url, genres = genres, born = born, ya = ya)` the variable `born` might not have been initialized, since you've took care of the initialization only inside one of the `if` cases.

Comment: There was no reason to downvote this perfectly good question.

Comment: You could add information about the specific line the error appears

Answer (score 0):

If you get that error, it simply means that you called or tried to assign a variable that does not exist.

To fix this, add `born = ""` *before* the function definition.

As a good way of checking, what you can do is give the variable `born` a default assignment, like `"Something went wrong."` or `0`. Then print out the variable before the function finishes executing. If it is stuck there, then you know the problem is in the `try/excepts.`

Answer (score 0):

You assign the `born` variable inside of your `for row in rows` loop.  The problem with this is that there may be no rows and hence no `born` assignment.

Place `born = "False"` before this loop.